# Python ValueError: cannot copy sequence to array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a .csv dataset with three columns formatted as follows

```
  t           X      Y
 0.040662  1.041667  1
 0.139757  1.760417  2
 0.144357  1.190104  1
 0.145341  1.047526  1
 0.145401  1.011882  1
 0.148465  1.002970  1
```

Instead of manually writing it as

```
x_final = np.array([1.041667, 1.760417, 1.190104, 1.047526, 1.011882, 1.002970])
v_observations = np.array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

I wanted to perform it automatically by copying the pandas dataframe to an array and here is my code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')
print(df)

df.dropna(inplace=True)

X = df.drop('Y', axis=1)
y = df['Y']

time = df.drop('t', axis=1)
print(X)
d1= np.array([X])
d2 = np.array([y])

x_final = np.array([d1])
y_final = np.array([d2])
z = np.c_[x_final, y_final]
```

However, I am getting this error when I try to run my code.

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 6 to array axis with dimension 2
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: how about: `z = df.dropna().drop('t', axis=1).values`

Comment: the error starts here `d1= np.array([X])` before reaching there when i try to run it line by line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr:** use [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)

Your issue is when you're creating your numpy arrays, you are passing it a list, when I think you are trying to pass it a dataframe:

```
# This doesn't work
np.array([X])
# This does
np.array(X)
```

So you can do:

```
d1= np.array(X)
d2 = np.array(y)
```

Or better yet:

```
d1 = X.values
d2 = y.values
```

To get:

```
>>> d1
array([[0.040662, 1.041667],
       [0.139757, 1.760417],
       [0.144357, 1.190104],
       [0.145341, 1.047526],
       [0.145401, 1.011882],
       [0.148465, 1.00297 ]])
>>> d2
array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

But in the end, your final result would be exactly the same as simply saying:

```
z = df.dropna().values
>>> z
array([[0.040662, 1.041667, 1.      ],
       [0.139757, 1.760417, 2.      ],
       [0.144357, 1.190104, 1.      ],
       [0.145341, 1.047526, 1.      ],
       [0.145401, 1.011882, 1.      ],
       [0.148465, 1.00297 , 1.      ]])
```

See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) for the `.values` method, which just gives you a numpy representation of a dataframe

Comment: This is very clean. But when I try to run `z`, it says `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`

Comment: I think you'll have much less of a headache by just using `z = df.dropna().values` from the start, rather than go through your whole complicated processing.

Comment: You are awesome. Even if it doesn't work out for me but I have to mark it an accepted answer. I am trying to reproduce this code and I don't know why It is not working out :( sad. `https://medium.com/@jaems33/understanding-kalman-filters-with-python-2310e87b8f48` He has put all the code at the end under `Putting it all together` and that's why I am trying to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

a I don't think that you even need to do all of those steps. Moving from a pandas data-frame to numpy 2D array is seamless.

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df_numpy = df.drop("t", axis=1).values
```